# EnumWindows in a nested class delphi

Tags: delphi, winapi

I've got some problems with `EnumWindows` function that uses callback function from a nested class:

```
TProcessWatch = class(TObject)
private
  ...
  type
    TProcessInfo = class(TObject)
    private
    type
      PEnumCallbackParam = ^TEnumCallbackParam;
      TEnumCallbackParam = class
        A : Integer;
        ...
      end;
    private
      FOwner : TProcessWatch;
      function FEnumWindowsCallback(hWindow : HWND; lParam : LPARAM) : BOOL; export;
      procedure SomeProc;
      ...
    end;
private
  FProcesses : TProcessInfo;
  ...
public
  ...
```

Within the `SomeProc` there is a call to `EnumWindows`

```
EnumCallbackParam := TEnumCallbackParam.Create;
try
  EnumCallbackParam.A := 0;
  EnumWindows(@TProcessWatch.TProcessInfo.FEnumWindowsCallback, LongInt(@EnumCallbackParam));
  ...
finally
  EnumCallbackParam.Free;
end;
```

And here is a `FEnumWindowsCallback` function listing:

```
function TProcessWatch.TProcessInfo.FEnumWindowsCallback(hWindow: HWND;
  lParam : LPARAM): BOOL; export;
var
  CallbackParam : PEnumCallbackParam;
begin
  CallbackParam := Pointer(lParam); // A is inaccessible
  Result := True;
  ...
end;
```

In runtime, when `EnumWindows` is called, `FEnumWindowsCallback` is always receiving `hWindow = 0` and `lParam` is pointing to inaccessible value.

All this working fine if callback function is declared private in the form, but when I've tried to make this function private in nested class it went wrong.

Why? And how to make this working? The goal is to make `FEnumWindowsCallback` and all other involved functions private in `TProcessWatch`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The callback is declared wrongly. It should be:

```
class function EnumWindowsCallback(hWindow: HWND; 
  lParam: LPARAM): BOOL; static; stdcall;
```

You were using the wrong calling convention, and an instance method.

Other comments:

- `EnumCallbackParam` is already a pointer. You can pass it as the param.
- Cast to `LPARAM` rather then `LongInt` so that you code will work if you ever compile to 64 bit.
- The `export` keyword has no meaning in 32 or 64 bit Delphi. It is ignored and you should not use it since it adds clutter and may confuse.